# How to write C++ function that accept unknown type&number of arguments?

Tags: c++, argument-passing

I want to write a function of this type:

```
void Print(void* args ...)
{
   while(args)
     cout<<args[i];
}
```

the funcdtion should handle int and (std::string or char*)

is it possible?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: concate variable type/number of arguments to one string

Comment: I am not sure whether `std::initializer_list` will work. I'vent used C++11 features. but you may give it a try

Answer (score 6):

You can do this with variadic templates:

```
void Print() { }

template <typename T, typename ...Args>
void Print(T const & t, Args const &... args)
{
    cout << t;
    Print(args...);
}
```

Comment: what about `std::initializer_list` ?

Comment: @NeelBasu: single type, limited in how you invoke it.

Comment: @NeelBasu `class printer_proxy { public: template<typename T> printer_proxy(const T& v) { std::cout << v; } }; void print(std::initializer_list<printer_proxy> list) { }`

Answer (score 4):

Answering

> [concatenation variable type/number of arguments to one string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14502786/how-to-write-c-function-that-accept-unknown-typenumber-of-arguments/14502920#comment20214117_14502786)

No need to write your own function for that, just use a `std::stringstream`:

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << intVar << stringVar << whatever;
```

Comment: Should be `stringstream` with an "m"